# Can a function called in an equality comparison know what it's being compared against?

Tags: php, equality

Is it possible to get string/int/function/or anything to compare in php function, if its used in `if` statement?

```
function return_str($str) {
    $value = valueToCompare(); // I want to get "cat" here

    if($str == $value) {
       return $value;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

```
if(return_str('abc') == 'cat') {
    echo 'No "abc" is not equal to "cat".';
}
```

Sorry if my function or example are a bit stupid, this should be part of larger script but I mimimized it.

Note: I don't want to hear *Why wouldn't you just type `if('abc' == 'cat')`*, because I must also handle multiple variables to check.

Do you have any ideas to achieve that? Please help me i'm not very good at these things.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do here?  What's the end goal?  There may be other solutions, but we need to know more in order to help find them.

Comment: @Charles I just want to save value to compare to a variable. Don't care about other things in my code example.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a second parameter?

```
<?php
function return_str($str, $compare) {
  if($str == $compare) return $str;
  return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, and is utterly pointless to try as well. If you want to compare a single string against multiple strings, why not

```
if (in_array('cat', array('dog', 'cat', 'zebra')) { 
   ... cat's in there
}
```

Comment: That's obviously a lie. It's easily possible with a combination of debug_backtrace, file_get_contents and token_get_all